# Terminology for an operator that inverts itself?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology

I am familiar with the term [involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29) for a function that inverts itself, and was wondering if there is a similar term for binary operators like XOR.  For example, $a \oplus b \oplus b = a$ for any $a$ and $b$.

Is there a term for operators like these?

Thanks!

Comment: A binary operation $\otimes$ on a set $S$ automatically defines two families of functions from $S$ to $S$: for each $a\in S$ we have $L_a:S\to S:s\mapsto as$ and $R_a:S\to S:s\mapsto sa$. Your condition amounts to saying that these functions are all involutions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)#Computer_science I think you just say it that way, "if you fix one parameter, than it's an involution".